# How do I create a documentation site on GitHub?

Tags: github, documentation

I wrote Hotplate, a great (and not yet complete) Nodejs framework which has, at this point, absolute 0 documentation.

It's no an "api" -- Hotplate is the kind of framework focused on "messages" being sent, and listened to, by several modules. So, documentation is tricky (it's *not* about documenting a bunch of functions, API-style).

My idea is to create, on Github, a site like Mongoose's:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

How would I do that for my own project?

Comment: Check out these frameworks: apache forest http://forrest.apache.org/flyer.html  Swagger https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/

Comment: The idea is to create something very simple, based on Markdown... swagger definitely isn't a good fit as mine is not an API...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github's recommended approach is to use [github pages](http://pages.github.com/) to host [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/).

You can use their "Automated Page Generator" to speed up the process.

See: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator